# consume min of n records and max n records but return records after waiting for m seconds

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am having a use case that consumer has to consume minimum of n records to start the next processing, but after waiting for m seconds, must return p records where p< n. Is there a way to achieve this in kafka?
i can configure min fetch size and max poll records to control the number of records but not sure how to implement the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `fetch.min.records` consumer property.

If your records are similar sizes, you can approximate your algorithm with `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`.

`max.poll.records` doesn't really help you, except when n records are already available.

Comment: thanks for the info..does fetch.min.bytes apply at partition level or topic level? If i am running 2 consumer instances with 2 partitions , will each consumer receive records after frtch.min.bytes in its assigned partition?

Comment: Yes; it's at the consumer level each consumer will wait for `fetch.min.bytes` or `fetch.max.wait.ms`, whichever occurs first.